# Kafka Stream:the final result emit immediately?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When the time window close,the final result emit immediately or when have new record come then emit?

```
val builder = StreamsBuilder();
   builder.stream<String,Double>(inputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), 
   Serdes.Double()))
        .groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(15)).grace(Duration.ZERO))
        .count()
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded())))
        .toStream()
        .print(Printed.toSysOut())
```

How to emit the final result immediately when the time window close?

Comment: I tested the code ,i commit three records in 15 seconds,but after few minutes,there is no result,until i commit a new record,then it emit the result 3.How to emit the final result immediately when the time window close?

Comment: I had same issue that the last windows didn't emit until a new message come out.
I endup made a stupid kafka producer to publish a dummy message to that topic every minute with a dummy key "hb", then it emitted the last window result.

Answer (score 0):

> How to emit the final result immediately when the time window close?

The final result is emitted immediately when the time window closes.

> or when have new record come then emit

However, the time window can only be safely closed, after a record with larger timestamp than the window-close time is processed.

A window cannot be safely closed based in wall-clock time -- `suppress()` is purely based on event-time, and event-time can only advanced records are processed.

Comment: But i tested the code ,i commit three records in 15 seconds,but after few minutes,there is no result,until i commit a new record,then it emit the result 3.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer: waiting advances wall-clock time but not event-time.